# Incorrect calculation of milliseconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, time

I'm trying to put together some javascript that will output an answer in milliseconds.

It's a script that calculates how long it will take to travel a certain distance.

At the moment it takes the numbers to be divided from text boxes on my page. It seems to do the division but the result isn't correct.

For example...
var a = 3.7 (distance) and var b = 25 (speed)

```
function journey_calc()
        {
            var a = +$("#txtDistance")[0].value; // example: 3.7 miles (distance)
            var b = +$("#txtSpeed")[0].value; // example: 25 mph (speed)
            var c = (a/b)/3600000; // returns the length of time it will take to travel the distance in hours, then divides by 3600000 to get the answer in milliseconds. 

            $(".journey-finder-result").text(c); //posts answer to span on page

        }
```

It "works" but "var c" is calculated incorrectly. Using the example above the answer should be 532800, but it returns 4.111111111111112e-8

The end goal is to convert the milliseconds into dd:hh:mm:ss form - am I approaching this incorrectly?

Many thanks!

Note: I am a newbie to javascript so I'm probably missing a very simple mistake!

Comment: This isn't a JS problem. 3.7/25/3600000 = 4.111111111111112e-8

Comment: When you were studying algebra in high school, were you one of the ones who said "I'll never need this when I grow up"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
var c =  a / b * 3600000;
```

It's a math problem, not JS. Fixed code:

```
function journey_calc()
        {
            var a = +$("#txtDistance")[0].value; // example: 3.7 miles (distance)
            var b = +$("#txtSpeed")[0].value; // example: 25 mph (speed)
            var c = a / b * 3600000; // returns the length of time it will take to travel the distance in hours, MULTIPLIED by 3600000 to get the answer in milliseconds.

            $(".journey-finder-result").text(c); //posts answer to span on page

        }
```

If you want to get the result in milliseconds, you should **multiply**

```
<HOUR> * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds
```

so, the `3600000` factor.

Comment: Well now I feel silly haha! Thanks Bacco, that works perfectly.